# Spring autowiring in dozer's destination class

Tags: java, spring, dozer

So, I was banging my head against the monitor for the last 4 hours and can't figure it out.
I am using Dozer for mapping and it works fine. However, I need one of my DAOs in the destination class and autowiring returns `null`. Here is a snippet of the class:

```
 @Component
 public class Address
 {
    @XmlElement(name = "street", required = true)
    protected String street;
    @XmlElement(name = "city", required = true)
    protected String city;
    @XmlElement(name = "zip", required = true)
    protected zip;


    @Autowired
    private CityDao cityDao;

    // Getters/setters 
  }
```

the `cityDao` is always `null`. I am fairly new to both Spring and Dozer, but the Dozer docs say that the destination classes are created with default constructors and as far as I understand the Spring should not have any problems with it. The `cityDao` is `null` though. Please help!

Comment: **Whoa.** This is a good time to re-evaluate what it is you're attempting to use that object for.  Mapping is really meant between two beans, and while the *mapping* may be a bit complex, you shouldn't need to wire anything additional in.  I would actually say that this situation calls for a custom converter, depending on what you're using that `cityDao` for.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely **not** be injecting anything into a DTO. Your DAOs should be injected into *services* which return either your entities or DTO versions of them. The entities/DTOs have no role here besides carriers of data.

Comment: ah, yeah it is initially started to be simple, but the new requirements rolled in and I'm trying to adjust with least of changes possible. Solid point guys, I'll have to think of some other ways around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you should **not** be injecting a DAO into a DTO!

However if you absolutely need to do that for some reason, check out Spring's `@Configurable` support. Here is the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html?is-external=true) and also some more information [here](http://seniorjava.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/spring-configurable-magic/) and [here](http://tamasgyorfi.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/spring-dependency-injection-configurable/).

If setup correctly, it allows objects that are not explicitly managed by Spring, to benefit from features like auto-wiring dependencies.

In you example code, `Address` although being annotated with `@Component`, is not managed by Spring since it's being created using Dozer. That's why you would need `@Configurable` to inject `CityDao` into `Address`

Comment: Ah, thanks I'll give it a try tomorrow, just for the sake of learning. Though, I do agree - the destination class should not have any injected DAOs in it, I'd better think of another solution to the problem. Thank you for the help!